# Javascript constructor creating new objects with same values as previously created object

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, reference

Here is my (simplified) constructor:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, setup); 
    }
}

const setup = {
    name: ''
}

export { User }
```

When I create a new object

```
import {
    User
} from './User.js';

let user1 = new User();
```

`user1` is what I expect.

If I declare `user1.name = 'John'` and then create another user `let user2 = new User()` then `user2.name` will be John, not an empty string.

Can someone explain why?

It appears `setup` is being changed and referenced instead of the new user object that was created.

Answer (score 3):

> It appears `setup` is being changed and referenced instead of the new user object that was created.

Yes. You need to make a copy of object before assigning it to instance of class

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, {...setup}); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally figured it out. This method works for shallow copying. I needed a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into similar issues, I finally figured it out. It boils down to shallow copying versus deep copying in Javascript. Both spread `(...)` and `Object.assign()` perform a shallow copy while JSON methods perform a deep copy.

If your setup is a nested object such as

```
const setup = {
    name: '',
    address: {
        city: ''
    }
}
```

the `address` object inside of `setup` will remain a referenced value, not a primitive value, when `{...}` or `Object.assign()` is used.

If you want to copy the whole object, you need to copy it as `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(setup))` so my constructor should be

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(setup))); 
    }
}
```

since this performs a deep (nested) copy.